# A problem in reloading the content of an Ajax tab programmatically?

Tags: jquery, jquery-events, jquery-ui-tabs

How can I set jQuery's ajax tab's url dynamically in runtime?

Doing like this:

```
$(function() {
    //$("#tabs").tabs();
    $("#tabs").tabs("url" , 0, "dep.php" );
});
```

html

```
<div class="flts">
    <div id="tabs">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="dep.php">Вылеты</a></li>
            <li><a href="arr.php">Посадка</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

but it's not working! What could be a problem?

Comment: Where's the closing tag for `<div id="tabs">`?

Comment: i have it in my code but here i copied it without enclosing </div>

Comment: Please fix your code so it contains valid HTML.

Comment: now i've corrected it!!!

Comment: Do you want to replace the whole tab widget at runtime, or just a single tab content?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach doesn't seem correct. The call of `$("#tabs").tabs("url" , 0, "dep.php")` is wrapped in `$(function() {`, so it's run only the first time the page is loaded. That makes no sense. This method is used to later replace the tab content.

The correct is approach is:

- The page should only contain the tab label with a valid link but no tab content.
- When the page is first loaded, call `$("#tabs").tabs();` to intialize and configure the tab widget.

The tab widget is now usable and the tab content is loaded when the specific tab is displayed for the first time (lazy loading).

- If you want to refresh or replace a tab later (e.g. from an event handler), call `$("#tabs").tabs("url" , 0, "dep.php")`.

So the overall solution could look like this:

```
<div class="flts">
  <div id="tabs">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="dep.php">Вылеты</a></li>
      <li><a href="arr.php">Посадка</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
</div>

$(function() {
    // intial tabs configuration
    $("#tabs").tabs();
    // event handler setup for refresh

    $('#refreshButton').click(function() {
      $("#tabs").tabs("url", 0, "dep.php?var=val&var2=val");
    });
});
```

Comment: The way I did after `$("#tabs").tabs("url", 0, "dep.php?var=val&var2=val");` row inserted one more row `$( "#tabs" ).tabs("load",0);` that urged to refresh and without `$( "#tabs" ).tabs("load",0);` it did not work at all.Now it's working fine! Thanks @Codo for your detailed answer !

Comment: Finally that's ! `$("#chngData")
   .button()
   .click(function() {
    $("#tabs").tabs("url",0,"dep.php?var="+$("#data").val());
    $( "#tabs" ).tabs("load",0);
   
  });`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to do the AJAX mode. If that be the case, then you need to specify the ajaxOptions. [This page](http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/#ajax) has a simple example which should set you straight.

Comment: I've already looked over it!!!  I simply need to change e.g. `<a href="arr.php">` `arr.php` to `arr.php?var=val&var2=val`